How to disable nested scroll when LazyColumn doesn't contain a lot of items?
I implemented nested scrolling in my app, and here it is the code:
val density = LocalDensity.current

    var headerSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0)) }
    val headerHeight by remember(headerSize) { mutableStateOf(with(density) { headerSize.height.toDp() }) }

    val headerOffsetHeightPx = remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val nestedScrollConnection = remember(headerSize) {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {
            val headerHeightPx = headerSize.height.toFloat()

            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                val delta = available.y
                val newOffset = headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue + delta
                headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue = newOffset.coerceIn(-headerHeightPx, 0f)
                return Offset.Zero
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
    ){
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .zIndex(1f)
                .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = headerOffsetHeightPx.floatValue.roundToInt()) }
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
        ) {
            val todayString = LocalDate.now().toFormattedString()
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .onSizeChanged {
                        headerSize = it
                    },
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.home_screen_header,todayString)
            )
        }

        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = headerHeight),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 16.dp).fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        ) {
            items(items = plantList, key = { plantDetail ->
                plantDetail.id
            }) {
                PlantListItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                        navigateToDetailScreen(it.id)
                    },
                    plant = it,
                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope
                )
            }
        }
    }

My problem is, when there is just 1 or two elements available inside the lazyColumn, I still able to swipe the Column with the Text inside it.
I think I need to decide somehow, if LazyColumn contains enough elements to fill the whole screen, and just after make the nestedScrolling enable.
What is the proper way to do it?

you can use Modifier.then() and add another Modifier param to decide whether the nestedScrolling  option should be enabled

Thanks, I know, but I don't know how I suppose to decide whether it is enabled or not? What should I check?

I think I figured out
      val isNestedScrollEnabled by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val layoutInfo = listState.layoutInfo
            val oneItemHeight = with(layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo){
                (getOrNull(1)?.offset ?: 0) - (getOrNull(0)?.offset ?: 0)
            }
            val notVisiblePartHeight = with(listState.layoutInfo){
                (totalItemsCount * oneItemHeight) - layoutInfo.viewportSize.height
            }

            notVisiblePartHeight >= headerSize.height
        }
    }

This code counts the height of remaining part of LazyColumn, and if this height is bigger or equal than the scrollable header height (headerSize) the nested scrolling will be enabled.
I'm testing it, but it seems to be working.
